# efficient way to find neighbors to specified cell?

Tags: r, matrix

Looking for sensible code to solve the following problem without a stack of "if" comparisons:

```
dput(acell)
structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(5L, 5L))
dput(bcell)
structure(c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), .Dim = c(5L, 5L))
```

It's guaranteed by construction (elsewhere in my code) that there is at least one nonzero entry in `bcell` in the four locations left,right,up,down one cell from the location of the nonzero value ([2,3]) in `acell` .  Is there some better way to return the indices of all such nonzero cells?   I'm currently using (pseudocode), for coords i,j referring to the nonzero element of `acell` ,

```
if( bcell[i-1,j]>0 ) found_values<-rbind(found_values,c(i-1,j))
if (bcell[i+1,j]>0 ) found_values<-rbind(found_values,c(i+1,j))
```

and so on.

Comment: There's a lot of stuff at http://ms.mcmaster.ca/~bolker/classes/m747/notes/durrettlevin.pdf that may be useful here.

Comment: You can use a sobel transformation on `a` and use it to subset `b`, I think that should work well.

Comment: @PascalvKooten Neat idea!  I've already got a sobel function in my pocket; off I go to try it out.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Let me know how that goes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility

```
# index of non-zero in acell
id <- which(acell == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)

# index of neighbors
rows <- id[1] + c(0, 0, -1, 1)
cols <- id[2] + c(-1, 1, 0, 0)

idx <- cbind(rows, cols)

# values of neighbors in bcell
vals <- bcell[idx]

# index of non-zero neighbors
idx[vals != 0, ]

#      rows cols
# [1,]    2    2
# [2,]    3    3
```

**Update**: An alternative

```
# index of non-zero in acell
id <- which(acell == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)
id

# create a matrix with cells adjacent to 'id'
# 'non-neighbor' cells are multiplied by zero
m <- matrix(c(0, 1, 0,
              1, 0, 1,
              0, 1, 0), ncol = 3) * 
  bcell[id[1] + (-1:1), id[2] + (-1:1)]

# index of non-zero neighbours
idx <- which(m != 0, arr.ind = TRUE)

# 'de-center' the centered indices
idx2 <- sapply(1:2, function(x) id[x] + (idx[ , x] - 2))

colnames(idx2) <- c("rows", "cols")
idx2
#      rows cols
# [1,]    2    2
# [2,]    3    3
```

Comment: I don't think either of these work when the 1 in `acell` is on the edge. If you `Filter` `rows` and `cols` in the first option to be between 1 and `nrow`/`ncol` `acell` it should work in that case. It will also return cell itself. I'm not sure if only neighbors or the cell itself should be returned

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment! I didn't have that constraint in mind. Perhaps @Carl Witthoft can clarify if this is necessary to consider? Cheers.

Comment: @JakeBurkhead   I figured I could deal w/ the edge cases ok by removing rows from `idx` .  I'd never noticed the note about  the behavior of `[` when fed a matrix for the indices ( `bcell[idx]`), so thanks for pointing that out.    And yes, don't return the cell location itself (although it'd be trivial to subset that out).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start:

```
dim <- dim(acell)

lookfor <- which(acell != 0)
lookup <- which(bcell != 0)

if (!((lookfor %% dim[1]) %in% c(1L,0L)) &
      !((lookfor %% dim[2]) %in% c(1L,0L)) ) {
  neighborsR <- lookup[abs(lookfor-lookup) == 1L]
  neighborsC <- lookup[(lookfor %% dim[1] == lookup %% dim[1]) &
                         abs(lookfor %/% dim[1] - lookup %/% dim[1]) == 1L]
}

neighbors <- c(neighborsR, neighborsC)

res <- cbind(neighbors %% dim[1], neighbors %/% dim[1]+1)
colnames(res) <- c("row", "col")
#     row col
#[1,]   3   3
#[2,]   2   2
```

This can only handle one `lookfor` value, which is not in the first/last row/column.

Comment: Looking for one at a time is ok for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
neighbors <- function(mat) {
  nr <- nrow(mat)
  nc <- ncol(mat)

  ones <- which(mat == 1)

  adjacent <- c(
    Filter(function(x) x %% nr != 0, ones - 1) ## above                                                                                                                                                                                       
    , Filter(function(x) x %% nr != 1, ones + 1) ## below                                                                                                                                                                                     
    , ones - nr ## left                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    , ones + nr ## right                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    )

  adjacent <- unique(Filter(function(x) x > 0 && x <= nr * nc, adjacent))

  out <- matrix(FALSE, nr, nc)
  out[adjacent] <- TRUE
  out

}

which(neighbors(acell) & bcell, arr.ind = TRUE)
##      rows cols                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
## [1,]    2    2                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
## [2,]    3    3
```

Comment: This is a good answer, and easily extensible.  I chose the other one because its simplicity suffices for my current needs.  Thanks for providing this code.